# How to draw simple wires in quantikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, quantikz

I want to make a way to redirect a line of a quantum circuit to other.

The perfect idea that i have is to use something similar to,

```
\begin{quantikz}
& \gate{H} & \gate[swap]{} & \qw & \qw \\
& \qw & & \gate{H} & \qw
\end{quantikz}
```

[image]

But only the line from one side, I mean that two lines merge in only one line.\

Other way to do it if is not possible like this will be something similar like this,

[image],

But I don't know how to plot a vertical line, I can only draw this lines with a dot using `\ctrl{1}`, but what is the command to plot a line without dots??

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After seraching in different manuals, I found a possible answer. I will post it for if is useful for someone. You can make vertical lines without points using, `\vqw{x}` where x is the vertical distance of the wire.

Is not exactly what I was seaching for, but it works.

Answer (score 3):

I assume you are looking for something similar to the first or second circuit.

[image: a]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{quantikz}

\begin{document}


\begin{quantikz}
    & \gate{H}  & \gate[swap]{} & \qw       &  \targ{}      & \gate[1]{H}   & \qw\\
    & \qw       &               & \gate{H}  &  \octrl{-1}   &               &
\end{quantikz}

\bigskip

\begin{quantikz}
    & \gate{H}  & \gate[swap]{} & \qw       &  \control{}   & \gate[1]{H}   & \qw\\
    & \qw       &               & \gate{H}  &  \octrl{-1}   &               &
\end{quantikz}

\end{document}
```